# 2D matrix in JS with row and column names

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have the following data structure:

```
const myMatrix = [[1,2], [3,4]];
```

Now, I would like to modify that data structure so that I can have row and column titles. So for example, if I were to render this matrix, it would look like:

```
-- Column1, Column2
Row1 1        2
Row2 3        4
```

Column1 and Column2 being the column titles and Row1 and Row2 being the row titles.

What would be the best JS structure to accommodate this?

Comment: dv, not me, but why is an array not suited for that?

Comment: where do you store the row/column names?

Comment: it depends, do you have a fixed count of columns and/or do you have for the rows a same pattern?

Comment: Are your row/column names known ahead of time, or are they set dynamically? Are they used for just printing, or do want to do something like myMatrix['column1'] = [4, 5, 6] ?

Comment: You could treat the column names as another row and the row names as another column and you'd get the structure: `[[undefined, "Column1", "Column2"], [ "Row1", 1, 2], ["Row2", 3, 4]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take an object as wrapper and the matrix as raw data, like

```
{
    cols: ['', 'Column1', 'Column2'],
    rows: ['Row1', 'Row2'],
    data: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
}
```

because this allows to address the matrix and make some calculations without converting and using the cols and row description as separate data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by rendering, but assuming you want to display it in your HTML, you just have to write some code. I don't know best practice, but this is what I came up with, let me know if you need explanation:

```js
const myMatrix = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
const anotherMatrix = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7]];

function matrixToSuperString(myMatrix) {
  let bodyString = "";
  let maxRowLength = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < myMatrix.length; i++) {
    if (myMatrix[i].length > maxRowLength) {
      maxRowLength = myMatrix[i].length;
    }
    let subArrayToString = `Row${i + 1}&#9;`;
    for (let elem of myMatrix[i]) {
      subArrayToString += `${elem}&#9;`;
    }
    bodyString += subArrayToString + "</br>";
  }
  
  let headerString = `--&#9;`;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < maxRowLength; i++) {
    headerString += `Column${i + 1}&#9;`;
  }
  
  return `<pre>${headerString}</br>${bodyString}</pre>`;
}

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML =
  matrixToSuperString(myMatrix) + matrixToSuperString(anotherMatrix);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

check it here: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/w06m3vxnp7

Answer (score 0):

I would set

```
const myMatrix = [ 
[row1col1,row2col1,rowNcolN],
[row1col2,row2col2,rowNcolN],
...
 ]
```

tranlated to your code should be

```
const myMatrix = [[1,3], [2,4]];
```

this data structure would be more efective in case of querying cols, your actual code could be more complex beacuse you must "walk" all arrays.

Comment: It's not clear how you're suggestion differs from the standard array?